# Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I'm trying to get the current logged in usersID in my jquery function

```
var userID = @User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Many answers on this page say that I have to do something like **`\"@User.Identity.GetUserId()\"`**
But it dont seem to work, can someone tell me how to fix it.

Its for my ajax post.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/video/check',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            userid: userID,
            streamid: defaultContext
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the response you are geting?

Comment: the error is Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to include it with the `'` mark

Like this : `var userID = '@User.Identity.GetUserId()';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` then 
your data should be stringified,

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    userid: userID,
    streamid: defaultContext
})
```

Ajax code,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/video/check',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        userid: userID,
        streamid: defaultContext
    })
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```